# Jira-type sprint reports in VSTS/Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, jira, reporting, sprint

Coming from a Jira shop to a VSTS one, I find the standard reports lacking.  I'm trying to find if there are any reports in Azure DevOps that would show the following:

- Stories added to the sprint (Stories after the sprint started)
- Stories removed from the sprint (Stories removed before work started)
- Incomplete stories (stories that have had work on them but not completed)

Or do I need to create custom queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you want to get the work items information from Azure DevOps, then yes, you could create custom queries like below: (Assume the sprint started date is `2018-08-11` here)

- Stories added to the sprint (Stories after the sprint started)

  [image]
- Stories removed from the sprint (Stories removed before work started)

  [image]
- Incomplete stories (stories that have had work on them but not
  completed)

  [image]